# How to show a Carbon dialog as part of a plugin for an application with an existing event loop?

Tags: macos, plugins, architecture, macos-carbon

I'm writing a plugin for an application and need to use Carbon to show a dialog. I have everything set up including the event handler, but I cannot possibly call `RunApplicationEventLoop()` because this would stall the host application.

How can I fix this? Will I need to create a separate thread and call `RunApplicationEventLoop()` from there?

-Joe

Answer (score 1):

What makes you think you need to call `RunApplicationEventLoop`?  The host app is presumably running an event loop, probably either using `RunApplicationEventLoop` or `NSApplicationMain`.  By the way, would your dialog be modal?  Modal is easier.